# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/projectShaun/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

When i start up the console i get no errors, however when i try to access the following url: http://localhost:8080/projectShaun/home i get the following error:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/projectShaun/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet

DispatcherServlet-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd" >

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun.controller" />

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <tx:annotation-driven/>
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectshaun" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.projectShaun</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop 
         key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
  </bean>
</beans>
```

HomeController:

```
package com.projectShaun.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.projectShaun.service.AccountService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("greeting", "Welcome to projectShaun!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: add `<display-name>projectShaun</display-name>` in the web.xml

Comment: @RahulThachilath I am still getting the 404 after adding this.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have welcome.jsp file in WEB-INF/jsp folder? That might be a problem, also you can check that your project context root are correct.(right click on project name -> properties -> web project settings -> in that Context root should be ProjectShaun)

Comment: Hi - that may be the problem, but this reads like a comment / clarification not an answer. To make it an answer you could e.g. explain what that file is and how it'd cause this problem, etc. - as is this might get deleted. Thanks!

Comment: @Rup I have no sufficient reputation for commenting. Updated my answer

Comment: @nileshvirkar yes my welcome.jsp is inside of WEB-INF/jsp folder. And i check my context root and it is projectShaun.